# Performing union of two arrays with custom rules

Tags: arrays, ruby, set, union

I have two arrays

```
b = ["John Roberts", "William Koleva", "Lili Joe", "Victoria Jane", "Allen Thomas"]

a = ["Jon Roberts", "Wil Koleva", "Lilian Joe", "Vic Jane", "Al Thomas"]
```

Currently I am using the union operator on these two arrays, like this: `a | b`. When combined, even though the names in each array are the "same" name (they're just using the shortened version of the name), it will duplicate my names.

My proposed solution to this is simply choose the first occurrence of first initial + last name as the name to perform the union on, however, I don't recall there being any methods in Ruby that can perform such an operation.

So the result of `some_method(a | b)` will return `c` which is just:

```
["John Roberts", "William Koleva", "Lili Joe", "Victoria Jane", "Allen Thomas"]
```

I am wondering how I could go about achieving this?

Comment: 1) Koleva/Koleba? 2) If you write real Ruby arrays it's easier for people to test the code.

Comment: I trust you don't mind the edit I did. I wanted to elaborate @tokland's comment and thought it would be easier to do the edit than to try to explain what he meant in words. Do you mean `some_method(a, b)`? If so, please edit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = ["John Roberts", "William Koleva", "Lili Joe", "Victoria Jane", "Allen Thomas"]
a = ["Jon Roberts", "Wil Koleva", "Lilian Joe", "Vic Jane", "Al Thomas"]

r = /
    \s           # match a space
    [[:alpha:]]+ # match > 0 alphabetic characters
    \z           # match end of string
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

(b+a).uniq { |str| [str[0], str[r]] }
  #=> ["John Roberts", "William Koleva", "Lili Joe", "Victoria Jane", "Allen Thomas"]
```

This uses the form of the method [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) that employs a block.

You may alternatively write `(b|a).uniq { |str| [str[0], str[r]] }`

The steps are as follows.

```
c = b+a
  # => ["John Roberts", "William Koleva", "Lili Joe", "Victoria Jane", "Allen Thomas",
  # "Jon Roberts", "Wil Koleva", "Lilian Joe", "Vic Jane", "Al Thomas"]
```

The first element of `c` passed to the block is

```
str = c.first
  #=> "John Roberts"
```

so the block calculation is

```
[str[0], str[r]]
  #=> ["J", " Roberts"]
```

The calculations are similar for all the other elements of `c`.  The upshot is that

```
c.uniq { |str| [str[0], str[r]] }
```

is equivalent to selecting the first elements of `c`, when converted to `[<first name initial>, <last name>]`, that match an element of the array `d`, where

```
d = [["J", "Roberts"], ["W", "Koleva"], ["L", "Joe"], ["V", "Jane"], ["A", "Thomas"],
     ["J", "Roberts"], ["W", "Koleva"], ["L", "Joe"], ["V", "Jane"], ["A", "Thomas"]].uniq
  #=> [["J", "Roberts"], ["W", "Koleva"], ["L", "Joe"], ["V", "Jane"], ["A", "Thomas"]]
```

Pascal suggested that it would be better for `uniq`'s block to return a string:

```
{ |str| "#{str[0]} #{str[r]}" }
```

(e.g., `"J Roberts"`) which might instead be written

```
{ |str| str.sub(/(?<=.)\S+/,"") }
```

The inclusion of the space after the first initial is optional (e.g., `"JRoberts"` would also work).

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to Ruby. Can you explain to me what this does?

Comment: I have a bit of an issue - this script does not seem to perform a union of my two sets, since if I run JUST `c = a | b` (with none of the code that is doing the `.uniq` operation), I get the union, however, if I run your script, it is missing some names. I tried both `(b+a).uniq..` and `(b | a).uniq..`.

Comment: Looks like if I use `str[1]` instead of `str[0]`, it works!

Comment: I do not follow your comments, but I added an explanation after you posted them. Does it now work for you? If not, please describe the array you want to be returned.

Comment: @CarySwoveland if you return a string from the block (```"#{str[0]} #{str[r]}"```)  then the code is more efficient. Of course it's more efficient than my solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use [Enumerable#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block:

```
c = (a | b).uniq do |full_name|
  first_name, last_name = full_name.split(nil, 2)
  [first_name[0], last_name]
end
```

Comment: For some reason, this script did not perform a union.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the first iteration of the code used the *initials* instead of *abbreviated* name.
Perhaps you can introduce the concept of a `Name`? It's a bit more code than just providing a block to `uniq` but it nicely encapsulates everything related.

```
class Name
  def initialize(first, last)
    @first, @last = first, last
  end

  def abbreviated
    "#{@first[0]} #{@last}"
  end

  def eql?(other)
    return false if !other.respond_to?(:abbreviated)
    abbreviated == other.abbreviated
  end

  def hash
    abbreviated.hash
  end

  def full
    "#{@first} #{@last}"
  end
end

a = Name.new('John', 'Roberts')
b = Name.new('Jon', 'Roberts')
c = Name.new('William', 'Koleva')
d = Name.new('Wil', 'Koleva')

x = [a, c]
y = [b, d]

p (y | x).map(&:full)
```

It's worth noting that abbreviated firstname does not really suffice to check equality of names.

Consider:

```
Jim Jackson
James Jackson
Janine Jackson
...
```